# Join query in Laravel 5.6

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a `Join` query like below in Laravel 5.6.

```
->join('employee', function ($join) {
                $join->on('company.surah_id', '=', 'employee.surah_id');
                $join->on('company.verse_id', '=', 'employee.ayah_id');
            })
```

I have a field `text` in `employee` table. I would like to fetch certain amount of character. More over I would like to fetch like below

```
"employee": {
     "text": "Jamal"
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with Eloquent models and relationships?

Comment: Thanks @JonasStaudenmeir. Yes, I am familiar with Eloquent model and relationships.